# "To experience person to person – artist to viewer – a shared sensation"

Tags: aesthetics, meaning

What does the second half of this paragraph mean?

> In viewing art, we recognise that we are not alone, confined by our mental and physical boundaries. We merge into a collective consciousness. Of course this happens in other circumstances, too, in rituals or riots, **but to experience person to person – artist to viewer – a shared sensation, the confirmation that someone can feel, if only for a split second, exactly as one does, provides a kind of elation to the lonely self and we sometimes need to return to an artwork to experience this reassurance.** (Sian Ede, [*Art and Science*](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=5_jVBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT130&lpg=PT130&dq=In%20viewing%20art,%20we%20recognise%20that%20we%20are%20not%20alone,%20confined%20by%20our%20mental%20and%20physical%20boundaries.&source=bl&ots=X9FbzZUNCV&sig=96nsuOKSZugo2RS3qwfwQedZ6xw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAGoVChMI8tKNgc_2xwIViCeUCh1ltA4Y#v=onepage&q=In%20viewing%20art%2C%20we%20recognise%20that%20we%20are%20not%20alone%2C%20confined%20by%20our%20mental%20and%20physical%20boundaries.&f=false))

Comment: There's probably an interesting philosophy question in there somewhere, but I don't understand what the concern is here - the artist feels something, depicts the feeling, the viewer then views the depiction, and feels the same feeling that the artist originally did.

Comment: yeah "self expression".

Comment: I am open to collective consciousness effects but "shared sensation" in perceiving a work of art is not a case of that. Perceptions and interpretations of paintings and music are not only culturally dependent, but notoriously divergent even among people with similar backgrounds. So the elation is not a confirmation or reassurance of commonality, it is an example of exalted self-suggestion.

Comment: I was just about to comment on that in spite of the age of this question to dissuade people from readings books that make ridiculous claims, but realized I don't need to anymore. Thanks, @Conifold.

Answer (score 2):

Famously Plato banned poets from his Republic; in one dialogue he had Socrates pokes a little fun at Ion, a rhapsodist - a singer of songs - for being unable to explain his gift for a rousing emotion in his audience.

Ion is actually a little afraid of Socrates questions; he wants to escape, perhaps he is thinking: stop thinking, Socrates and listen; listen to my song, and allow yourself to be carried away; then you'll understand - that just by listening naturally, one understands with no explanation ever being articulated or even found neccessary.

But Socrates persists, for he is a persistent man; eventually he explains it for Ion: he says Ion, when he sings - and especially when he sings well; he  is not himself, he is transported out of himself (*ekstasis* - out+stand) and by virtue of his art, he is able to do the same for his audience.

They, the audience, when listening to his song, are reliving or anticipating a passion - the same passion; so they are brought to a kind of unity where not:

> 'being confined by our mental and physical boundaries'

We realise we are not alone; and see each other, eye-to-eye.

This explains the first paragraph.

The second paragraph is the same, said differently and more intimately; for there is no suggestion of an audience, but only you and an artwork - perhaps a piece of music, perhaps walking into a courtyard, or a painting glanced at; or again, a book of poems, as in the answer by @Barzell.

Another example along the same lines, but in a quieter key is to glance at a painting by Vermeer, and recognise a moment of contemplation in a moment of aloneness; which Vermeer too must have felt to have chosen this moment to paint; and that fills that moment and erases the aloneness and connects artist to the viewer in a moment of recognition; some spark of spirit abolishes time and distance; and therefore brings

> 'a kind of elation for the lonely self'

Which even if not glanced at again, but recalled later - perhaps much later, brings back that

> 'experience of reassurance'

One is indeed, again, not alone.

Answer (score 1):

Art (paintings, stories, etc...) speak to the human condition and this serves to alleviate suffering.  Why?

When I suffer, there is an loneliness to the suffering, a feeling that it's just me who's in pain and the rest of the world is happy.  So now on top of the pain, I feel marginalized.

For instance, let's say I'm suffering due to a romantic breakup.  Well, that's bad enough, but now when I walk the streets, I notice seemingly happy couples everywhere.  They all have someone, yet I'm alone.

Then I pick up a poem about love lost, read it, and feel someone else has suffered what I suffered. Someone understands this! Better yet, that this poem is known by others seems to indicate that they too felt it spoke to them.  Now I may suffer pain, but I'm no longer an outcast; I'm part of humanity, playing my role in experiencing the human condition.

In this shared suffering, I find solace, or to put it less charitably, misery loves company.

For an interesting comparison/contrast, check out [Schopenhauer's Aesthetic Theory](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/schopenhauer-aesthetics/). While he elevates connection to a universal level, the connection and relief from suffering are there.